# Can a digital banner access my facebook data?

Tags: facebook, banner

On a rich media banner, which obviously would appear on several different sites, is it possible to access a user's facebook information such as their photos?

The user would need to grant permission to the banner -- not sure if that's possible though.

Comment: What do you mean by "banner" ?

Comment: A rich media banner that you would see on the NY times etc....

Answer (score 1):

There is some Facebook information that is publicly accessible to "anonymous" applications (i.e. unauthenticated/unauthorized). These include but are not limited to name and profile picture. It really depends on how public a user's profile is. However, I'm not sure you can get whatever the currently viewing user's info is. That's typically gotten by making an API request to /me which requires being authenticated.

However, if you're authenticated by the user, you can use whatever information they've granted you access to (specified by you during the OAuth process).